# An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. What to do?

Tags: c#

```
public ActionResult Applicant(int JobPostId)
{
    List<JobSeeker> jobSeekers = new List<JobSeeker>();
    var ApplicationList = db.JobApplications.Where(x => x.JobPostId == JobPostId).ToList();

    foreach(JobApplication app in ApplicationList)
    {
        jobSeekers.Add(db.Users.OfType<JobSeeker>().Single(x => x.Id == app.JobSeekerId));
    }
    // var JobseekerForJobPost = db.Users.OfType<JobSeeker>().Where(x => x.JobPostsAppliedFor.Any(y => y.JobPostID == JobPostId)).ToList();

    return View(jobSeekers);
}

@Html.ActionLink("View Applicants", "Applicant", new { id = item.JobPostID }) |


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I cannot figure it out why it is giving me error.

Comment: Where are you seeing that error

Comment: When i click to View applicant

Answer (score 3):

Your action method has a value type parameter (an `int`):

```
public ActionResult Applicant(int JobPostId)
```

But you're not supplying the route with a value for it:

```
Html.ActionLink("View Applicants", "Applicant", new { id = item.JobPostID })
```

The error is telling you that you must supply a value for that parameter, because an `int` can't otherwise be `null`.  If you want this value to possibly be `null`, make it nullable:

```
public ActionResult Applicant(int? JobPostId)
```

Or, if it *shouldn't* be nullable, provide a value for it:

```
Html.ActionLink("View Applicants", "Applicant", new { JobPostID  = item.JobPostID })
```

(From your usage of that value in that action method, it looks like it *shouldn't* be `null`.  But I suppose it's *possible* that it could be in your data.)

---

Side note: By C# convention variables should be lowecase:

```
public ActionResult Applicant(int jobPostId)
```

and:

```
Html.ActionLink("View Applicants", "Applicant", new { jobPostID  = item.JobPostID })
```

Comment: @ToniJeličić: That's a completely different error.  That one is telling you that when you `return View()` from your `Applicant` controller action, there's no actual view to be returned.  Did you forget to create a view for this?

Comment: @ToniJeličić: Then it sounds like someone published broken code to their source control.  Or perhaps you've made some mistake along the way.  Either way, the error is still very specific about the problem.  There is no view corresponding to that controller action.  So the `return View()` statement results in an error.  You'll either need to correct this or contact whoever maintains the code to correct it.

Comment: @ToniJeličić: Well, I guess good luck with that.  There are a variety of places online where you can hire a programmer, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @ToniJeličić: This comment thread is very much deviating from the original question, which has been asked and answered.  There is much more help you can get from this community, but the format here is questions and answers, not personalized tutoring.  For your latest error message, what it means is that `GetUserId()` can't be translated into a database query.  So it needs to be executed in the code, not in the database expression.  If you're having trouble with that, it sounds like it could make for another Stack Overflow question.  (Possibly a duplicate, so definitely search first.)

Comment: I understand all David, thank you alot for your answers i will try to read them carefully and hopefully get to the answer how to solve my issues. I hope one day i will answer your questions too. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Just make your parameter

```
public ActionResult Applicant(int JobPostId)
```

optional

```
public ActionResult Applicant(int? JobPostId)
```

In the routing it's mapped as optional thats why you have to make it nullable